# How to fit the video Width & Height with respect to vitamio video view in android

Tags: android

Am developing android stream player for Android Box(smart TV),
for that am using Vitamio to play my m3u8 stream on android.
every thing is fine but the problem is videoview size could not be controlled, i.e, while playing video the Videoview overlaps on other controls.

In The Fist screen shot the black colored area is the videoview,

while playing video the videoview size changed with respect to video which is exactly in Second screen shot.

How can I fit the video size respect to videoview ???

If Need any code for clear idea let me knw,. Am really struct here pls Help me,.

First :
[image]

Second :
[image]

Comment: You could try setting the size of videoview to wrap_content in height.

Comment: Can we use vitamio player free in our paid android app?

Comment: yes v can coz vitamio is a opensource,.

Answer (score 0):

From VOV IO's web-site (vitamio VOVIO - focus on Android multimedia application):

---

Vitamio is a multimedia framework for all Android devices. Vitamio works like the Android's default MediaPlayer except that it includes much more powerful features. And it's absolutely free !

Network Protocols:
The following network protocols are supported for audio and video playback:

MMS
RTSP (RTP, SDP)
HTTP progressive streaming
HTTP live streaming (M3U8), for Android 2.1+

Media formats:
Many audio and video codecs are packed into Vitamio beside the default media format built in Android platform, some of them are listed below.

divx/xvid
wmv
flv
ts
rmvb
mkv
mov
m4v
avi
mp4
3gp

Subtitles:
Vitamio support the display of many external and embedded subtitle formats.

SubRip(.srt)
Sub Station Alpha(.ssa) / Advanced Sub Station Alpha(.ass)
SAMI(.smi/.sami)
MicroDVD(.sub/.txt)
SubViewer2.0(.sub)
MPL2(.mpl/.txt)
Matroska (.mkv) Subtitle Track

More features:
There are more wonderful features available in Vitamio.

Background playback
Multiple audio tracks support
Mutitiple subtitles support, including external and embedded ones
Processor optimization for many platforms
Buffering when streaming
Adjustable aspect ratio
Automatically text encoding detection

---

So VitamioB4A is a B4A-Wrapper of the Vitamio-plugin. The plugin is an Android APK which includes a collection of media demuxers, decoders, filters besides some video and audio output libraries. If the user does not have the plugin installed, the user will be prompted to download and install it from Google Play. Since the first release of the B4A-wrapper, many other features have been added and now mostly the subtitles-features of the VideoView-class are missing.

Note: android:minSdkVersion="8"

VitamioB4A allows you to play video media inside your applications. The difference from the standard Android-VideoView is that VitamioB4A supports much more formats and codecs since it is based on FFMPEG.